# Native Mobile Application client side page to page response times

Tags: performance, mobile, native, nativeapplication

Is there a tool to measure native mobile app (can be iOS or Andriod) client side pape to page response times? I found MIHTool (mobile app) that can help us to get HTTP traffic trace like firebug does for Mobile browser based application but not for native mobile app. Would appreciate your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I am the creator of MIHTool,if you want to measure native mobile app,all you need to do is use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to set up a proxy from you pc,then set your phone's wifi's proxy to you pc's local ip address.

PS: MIHTool helps more then 50K devs right now,I'd love to post it here so more and more devs can make their job ease and help me to make MIHTool better, but I got banned to post as ADs.